# Rails 3 - Issue with Nested Routes, It's not allow for a custom collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in my routes.rb:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :photos, :permissions
    collection do
        get 'yourcurrentprojects', 'userprojectpermission'
    end
end
```

But when I do, projects/3/permissions/userprojectpermission
i get a routing error: No route matches "/projects/3/permissions/userprojectpermission"

Did I define this wrong? Thank you for your help

Comment: run "rake routes". what does it say? play around. Try symobolize in collection, e.g. get :symbolizedmethod

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `projects/permissions/userprojectpermission`.